# Number of unique integer coordinate points in an $n$- dimensional hyperbolic-edged tetrahedron

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, definite-integrals, volume, symmetry

I want to calculate the number of unique **integer** coordinate points inside an $n$-dimensional solid space. My approach is to approximate the number of points as the volume enclosed by the solid and then remove duplicates by considering the axes of symmetry.

eg. for $n=2$ let the equation of the curve be $(a+x) \times (a+y) \leqslant L$ where $x,y \geq 0$. So the number of within the area can be found by integration and we can remove the duplicates by considering the line of reflection passing thru the origin and cutting the hyperbola at the midpoint. Sample image:

[image]

So I want to generalize this solution for $n$-dimensions. For $n=3$ (when the equation is $(a+x)×(a+y)×(a+z) \leqslant L$). I am thinking of approximating the volume by considering a tetrahedron as integral is very hard to solve. But still the problem of removing duplicates is there.

One obvious axis symmetry cuts the tetrahedron in half but beyond that I don't know how I should proceed.

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand this concept of removing duplicates. Isn't a point at a symmetric position just as inside the shape as one away from the axis of symmetry? I'd be more concerned about the squares near the curve, which are partially inside and partially outside the shape so they contribute less area per grid point than those inside.

Comment: well the problem which I am working on needs me to remove duplicates.

For squares near the boundary I think we can get a bound using the length of the curve.

Comment: Ok so I searched for Gauss's circle problem which is similar to what I want and I found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Dirichlet's_divisor_problem which is almost exactly what I'm looking for.

But still the problem of removing duplicates is remaining.